# How to switch to another view

Tags: cocoa-touch, xcode, uiviewcontroller

The following code should work, right?

```
ViewController2 *childView = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:childView animated:YES];
 [childView release];
```

It doesn't do anything though. There are no error messages. The view just doesn't get switched. viewDidLoad does not even execute inside ViewController2.

Comment: Have you debugged it at all? Is childView nil?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code won't do anything if the view controller presenting it doesn't have a navigation controller, i.e. it isn't in a navigation controller stack. In that case, you'll be calling a method (`pushViewController:animated:`) on a nil object (`self.navigationController`) which does nothing. Thus, you can only use this this method if the "parent" view controller is in a `UINavigationController` stack.

Comment: I tried that code and it crashed saying unrecognized selector.

Comment: It's saying unrecognized selector because that class doesn't know about that method, which means `self` isn't a `UIViewController` or subclass. Where are you calling the code from? Please post more code so there's more context. (My gut tells me you're doing this from inside a **view** class.)

Comment: I'm using a UIViewController but it's in a view-based application not a nav-based application.

Comment: Oh, oops. Yeah, that's the problem. You can only push view controllers onto a navigation stack. Sorry for that. I will amend my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
[self presentModalViewController:viewControllerNameHere animated:YES];
```